# TextField's background color reverts back to default state a few milliseconds after it was changed in a property didSet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, colors

I'm trying to get a color selection view to pass the color to the Master view controller's textLabel. After the color is passed, it calls a didSet of a property which changes the textLabel's background color to the selected color. However, the background color visibly reverts back to the default color.

I've set breakpoints through the code and I've found that the initial viewDidLoad of the Master VC did not call when going back from the color Selector VC to the MasterVC, and the colors were correct at the end of the execution, and nothing that could override a color change ran.

However, when a new color is selected and sent back to the Master VC, the textLabel's text shows the correct color, but the color of the label is correct for a brief moment but relapses.

Does anybody know what is going on? My code is below

This is the Master View Controller. Color here is in hex, while colorName is simply the name of the color (eg. red)

```
class AddProjectTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: - Properties
var color: String = Color.toHex("Red")

var colorName: String? = "Red" {
    didSet {
        if let newColorName = colorName {
            let colorHex = Color.toHex(newColorName)
            self.color = colorHex

            colorLabel.text = "   \(newColorName)"
            colorLabel.backgroundColor = Color.toUIColor(colorHex)

        }
    }
}

//MARK: - IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var colorLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    colorLabel.text = "    \(colorName ?? "Choose Color")"
    colorLabel.backgroundColor = Color.toUIColor(color)
    print(color)
}

//MARK: - Functions
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PickColor" {
        if let colorPickerVC = segue.destination as? 
PickColorTableViewController{
            colorPickerVC.selectedColorName = colorName
        }
    }
}


// MARK: - IBActions
@IBAction func unwindWithSelectedColor(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let colorPickerVC = segue.source as? 
PickColorTableViewController {
        guard let chosenColorName = colorPickerVC.selectedColorName,
        let chosenColorHex = colorPickerVC.selectedColorHex
            else { return }

        self.color = chosenColorHex
        self.colorName = chosenColorName
    }
}
}
```

My colorPicker View Controller is here.

```
class PickColorTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: - Properties
var colors: [String] = ["Red", "Maroon", "Yellow", "Olive", "Lime", 
"Green", "Aqua", "Teal", "Blue", "Navy", "Fuchsia", "Purple"]

var selectedColorName: String? {
    didSet {
        if let selectedColor = selectedColorName {
            let index = colors.index(of: selectedColor)
            selectedColorIndex = index
            let selectedHex = Color.toHex(selectedColor)
            selectedColorHex = selectedHex
        }
    }
}

var selectedColorHex: String?

var selectedColorIndex: Int?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.reloadData()
}

//MARK: - Functions
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "SaveSelectedColor",
    let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    else { return }

    self.selectedColorName = colors[indexPath.row]
}


// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return colors.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", 
    for: indexPath)
    let colorName = colors[indexPath.row]
    let colorHex = Color.toHex(colorName)
    let color = Color.toUIColor(colorHex)

    if indexPath.row == selectedColorIndex {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = colorName
    cell.backgroundColor = color

    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if let index = selectedColorIndex {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, 
section: 0))
        cell?.accessoryType = .none
    }

    selectedColorName = colors[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
}
```